# Extracting an image portion opencv C + +

Tags: c++, image, opencv, extract

I am trying to create a project that extract parts of an image, knowing that I have determined the contour points and I determined points related envelope and now I want to calculate the surface of the parties are between the edge points and the points of the envelope  without matrices because i used poiters.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: can you add an example image that illustrates what you want to extract/compute?